# Why pdf files downloads as corrupted?

Tags: java, http, url, file-io, download

I wrote small program for downloading files via url. Every other files format I can open properly, but for downloaded pdf it's impossible.

```
public static void saveFile(String fileUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }
    os.flush();
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Do I need special way for handling pdf downloads?

When I try to get selected pdf via URL in browser it's displays properly

**EDIT**

Added flush() to code, still no success

Trying to open damaged pdf in browser (FF) returns error:

> File does not begin with '%PDF-'

Adobe Reader returns:

> File could not be open because it is either not a supported file type
>   or because file has been damaged.

Damages pdf has smaller size (about 80%) than original

Comment: Are *large* Movie files being downloaded correctly?

Comment: @pst there aren't movies file, only text (pdf, doc, xls) and images

Comment: Try it with a different *binary file* format of similar (or larger) size as the PDF. Or is the issue only isolated to *a particular server*?

Comment: @pst I think file size doesn't matter because I am downloading doc files bigger than these pdfs

Comment: @pst I downloaded quite big movie file with success

Comment: While I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code, it might be neater to use the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), in particular [IOUtils.toByteArray](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.net.URL%29)

Comment: Did you try downloading the same files with a web browser or a tool like wget? Does that work?

Comment: Does downloading PDFs from *all* servers fail or just that server? Also, what error(s) are there when opening the PDFs? (This is quite a puzzling question, and I'd hate to suspect something sneaky on the network.)

Comment: @ArnoutEngelen Yes via web browser works :/

Comment: @pst I found some pdf that works, but most of them doesn't

Comment: Are there obvious differences between the PDFs or are they are downloaded from different servers? Is the non-browser PDF viewer up-to-date (or the same program as) the internal PDF viewer? I have had good luck using Foxit PDF Reader.

Comment: When you have the file downloaded with a web browser and with your tool, can you use a diff tool to tell in what way it is broken? For example, is the file truncated or does it seem like some kind of encoding conversion issue?

Comment: Does the file indeed not begin with `%PDF-`? Is it empty? What does it begin with? Does it actually contain a HTML error page or something like that?

Comment: Can you open up the file in an editor (or a binary editor) -- what does it look like? How does it start? Could the server have returned non-PDF data for some reason?

Comment: I'm so dumb, damaged files has HTML code inside.

Comment: Anyway I am wonder why I am getting this html. it is not website error page.

Comment: Write up the problem as an answer and then accept it :) This will allow this question to be "completed" and will let future readers know of the issue and what is one thing to look for.

Comment: As far as *where* the HTML comes from, it likely has to do with a different server response based on the headers sent by the client. Also what the HTML *says* might be a clue.

Comment: @pst Right, thanks for advices

Comment: This works fine. I just tested.

Answer (score 1):

The damaged pdf files has website html code inside.

Comment: When/if you find out *why* this occurs, and how to get around it (perhaps use HttpClient?), expand this answer.

Comment: Your code works fine, make sure you have no firewall and you get the right URL.